# Give more accurate result on touch event

Tags: android, touch, onclicklistener, motionevent

I am trying to make a big click on touch screen(e.x when a fat finger press it) smaller, which means to give the more accurate result depending on the center of the click. My problem is i can't find a relevant post or a way how to make a touch event smaller(like..concentrate).

*Please feel free to ask anything if you didn't get me.*

Comment: I have created the code to get the current coordinates of the finger press

Comment: Could you include the code you've tried?

Comment: No no, i have successfully created the code to get the touch coordinates but not to make them 'smaller', more accurate

Comment: I would recommend writing some code and trying it first. The precision for "fat" touches may already be more accurate then you expect. If not, there are tons of public methods for MotionEvent that can help you get more "precise" touches.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? -thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a [sample application in the Google Play store called Markers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dsandler.apps.markers) which admirably demonstrates the ability to do what you want - to do pressure sensitive touch events.

Fortunately this app is open source, so [check out its code](http://code.google.com/p/markers-for-android/).

Note however the page [listing known problem devices](http://code.google.com/p/markers-for-android/wiki/DeviceSupport).

Comment: Altought that's not what i asked for.